# Use a range of cells as criteria in SUMIF

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

As an example, I have the below formula:

```
=SUMIF(G1:G25,E1,H1:H25)+SUMIF(G1:G25,E2,H1:H25)+SUMIF(G1:G25,E3,H1:H25)
```

It is 3 SUMIFs all using the same criteria and sum range, the criteria uses 3 cells all in the same range.

I want to be able to condense this formula to something like the below:

```
=SUMIF(G1:G25,E1:E3,H1:H25)
```

where the criteria is the range of cells.
I have tried:

```
{=SUMIF(G1:G25,E1:E3,H1:H25)}
```

&

```
=SUMIF(G1:G25,{E1:E3},H1:H25)
```

&

```
=SUM(SUMIF(G1:G25,{E1:E3},H1:H25))
```

Is there a way to achieve this ? perhaps even with `SUMPRODUCT` ?

Also, in place of the range `E1:E3` I would like to use a named range, if possible, If not just a way of condensing the multiple SUMIFs will do for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The smallest possible Formula I would like to suggest is:*

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A7,A9:A11,0))*B1:B7)
```

[image]

**Your Formula should be re-written like shown below:**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(G1:G25,E1:E3,0))*H1:H25)
```

*You may adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: You seem to have succeeded where I didn't so I deleted my wrong answer.  You condensed the OP's formula a fair bit using SUPRODUCT, ISNUMBER and MATCH, and being there is the range `E1:E3` used, a named range can be used in its place.

Comment: I knew there would be a way using `SUMPRODUCT`, thanks Raj

Comment: @PeterH,, glad to help you.. please keep asking ☺

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS())`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A,D1:D3,B:B))
```

The SUMPRODUCT forces the iteration of the Criteria.  The others can be full column without detriment.  It is basically doing 3 SUMIF()s and adding the results.

FYI: You can also do with SUM: `=SUM(SUMIF(A:A,D1:D3,B:B))` as long as you Array enter with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.

[image]

Comment: I was closes with `=SUM(SUMIF(G1:G25,{E1:E3},H1:H25))` I put the criteria in curly brackets, rather than the whole formula, thanks for the answer, this is very useful as I am assuming it will also work with SUMIFS also

Comment: @PeterH yes it will work with SUMIFS,COUNTIF, and COUNTIFS.